# linux kernel: Create a delayed real time workqueue

Tags: linux-kernel, real-time, delay

i have a module that activate a timer and when the timer expired it schedule an work for a rt-wq.
Is it possible to replace it with a delayed rt-wq? Is there such thing as a delayed rt-wq? if so i can't find the documentation for it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The work to be scheduled can be delayed. So, delays may not be a property of the queue...it is a property of the scheduled work. Look at `schedule_work` vs `schedule_delayed_work`.